# Page Controller has no clients

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement page controller with dots indicator and auto scrolling dots but the page controller always shows it has no clients. I've attached the page controller to the page view builder controller. I'm using flutter hooks instead of using stateless or stateful widgets.

I'm using **useEffect** to initialise the timer to auto scroll the pages. I'm fetching the pages from the firebase Firestore and then starting the timer. Even though the dots indicator changes but the page controller has always no clients.

In build method at the top, I'm initialising the page controller.

I've searched the internet, tried to find the solution to my problem but it seems I'm doing something wrong as I couldn't find any relevant problems or solutions.

```
PageController pageController = PageController(
  initialPage: 0,
  viewportFraction: 0.88,
);
```

**Use Effect**

```
useEffect(() {
  if (controller.bannersList.isEmpty) {
    controller.fetchBannerInfo();
  }

  // Starting the timer
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    startBannerTimer();
  });
  return null;
}, []);
```

**Timer method**

```
void startBannerTimer() {
  // auto scroll page view banners
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
    final totalBanners = controller.bannersList.length - 1;
    if (currentBannerIndex.value < totalBanners) {
      currentBannerIndex.value++;
    } else {
      currentBannerIndex.value = 0;
    }

    if (pageController.hasClients) {
      print('client attached');
      pageController.animateToPage(currentBannerIndex.value,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          curve: Curves.easeIn);
    } else {
      print('No client attached => ${pageController}');
    }
  });
}
```

**Page View Builder**

```
Obx(() => Container(
                height: 200,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                child: PageView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: pageController,
                  itemCount: controller.bannersList.value.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return fetchBannerView(
                        controller.bannersList.value[index]);
                  },
                ),
              )),
```

**Dots Indicator**

```
   Obx(() => controller.bannersList.value.isNotEmpty
              ? Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                  child: DotsIndicator(
                    dotsCount: controller.bannersList.value.length,
                    position: currentBannerIndex.value.toDouble(),
                    decorator:
                        DotsDecorator(color: AppColors.primaryLightColor),
                  ),
                )
              : Container()),
```

Comment: hey did you sove it ? i got the same issue :<